# Firefox goes full screen when dragged from secondary to primary monitor

Tags: firefox, 17.10, window-manager, cinnamon, tiling

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 using the cinnamon desktop

I have 2 monitors and in my second (secondary) monitor, when Firefox is maximized and I grab it from the bar on top and try to drag it onto my primary one, it goes full screen (like when you press <kbd>f11</kbd>), this happens only in Firefox (I'm using nightly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by adding a panel to the screen that had the issue